# Как правильно закрывать процесс node.js?

Tags: node.js, cron

Запускаю по крону js скрипт на сервере, явно указывая путь к node.js `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin/node /var/www/www-root/app/core/control.js`.
Все работает как надо,но получается вот такая вот картина расходования оперативной памяти[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю это из за того,что процесс node.js не закрывается после выполнения скрипта.Как мне правильно его закрывать? Использовать process.exit()?

Answer (score 2):

Если NodeJS продолжает работать по окончанию скрипта, то значит скрипт ваш на самом деле не закончил работать, к примеру остались висеть ожидающие исполнения "setInterval'ы", не закрытые потоки, или слушатели событий '.on'.
Да использование "process.exit()" в основном потоке безболезненно завершит исполнение NodeJS, но вы сами должны быть уверены, что скрипт явно сделал свою работу.